# Tabla de porcentajes con valores perdidos con el paquete expss en R

Tags: r, rstudio, tablas, packages

Tengo una base de datos a partir de la cual necesito trabajar una serie de tablas cruzadas. Para ello estoy usando el paquete expss. Mi problema es que al sacar los porcentajes por columnas estos parecen no tomar en cuenta los NA. Quisiera saber de qué manera podría mantener los NA dentro del total de casos y que estos sean colocados en la tabla cruzada como "sin información". El bloque de códigos que estos usando es el siguiente

```
  Data|>
  tab_cells(mdset(a001 %to% a007) )|> #conjunto de respuestas de opción múltiple dicotómicas
  tab_cols(total(), SEXO)|> #variable con valores "mujer, hombre y prefiero no decir"
  tab_weight(PESO)|> #factor de ponderación
  tab_stat_cpct()|>
  tab_pivot()
```

Los totales son calculados por columna según el SEXO. En algunos casos las personas que debían contestar un o varias de las respuestas desde la a001 a la a007 no marcó ninguna. Eso debería registrarse como sin información. El paquete, al momento de generar la tabla solo considera las respuestas válidas. Quisiera sí las considerar y que se genere una fila con esos porcentajes en la tabla cruzada.

Actualización:

Resolví el problema de considerar los NA de dentro del total casos contados para el porcentaje. Sin embargo, aun no he podido crear una nueva fila que diga "Sin información" y que me muestre esos NA. El código quedaría editado de la siguiente forma:

```
  Data|>
  tab_cells(mdset(a001 %to% a007) )|> #conjunto de respuestas de opción múltiple dicotómicas
  tab_cols(total(), SEXO)|> #variable con valores "mujer, hombre y prefiero no decir"
  tab_weight(PESO)|> #factor de ponderación
  tab_stat_cpct_responses(total_statistic = "w_responses")|>
  tab_pivot()
```

Quisiera saber si estoy en lo correcto, si estoy el calculando según el total de casos y no solo de las respuestas válidas.